# Examples of Many-one reductions.

Tags: computability

I'm trying to wrap my head around many-one reductions for an assignment in Mathematical Logic.

The assignment is to show

$A$ r.e $\Leftrightarrow$ $A\leq_m K$ where $K=\{x\in\mathbb{N}\ |\ x\in W_x\}$

($W_x$ is the domain of the (Turnip-)program having code $x$)

I don't want you to solve this explicitly but rather give examples of many-one reductions to help me reason about them. I've tried using Google for this but haven't found anything that helps me.

**Can you give examples of recursively enumerable sets that easily can be reduced to K?**

For reference:

$A\leq_m B$ iff there is a total recursive function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in A\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in B$

Comment: Presumably, the spelling corrector changed Turing to turnip...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Nope, it is actually the correct one. I have only seen it in my course book though http://www.oup.com/us/catalog/general/subject/Mathematics/Logic/~~/dmlldz11c2EmY2k9OTc4MDE5ODUyOTgwNA== 

One defines $T^{++}$-programs on Turnip machines. It's kinda silly.

Comment: Ah, it's probably using something different enough from Turing machines to make the Johor want to avoid using that name

Comment: The way I think about $A \leq_{m} B$ is that we can determine if $a \in A$ (or not) by asking a single, effectively determinable question about $B$. So if we have knowledge of $B$ (i.e. you can always tell if $b\in B$), the we also have knowledge of $A$ (since we have access to $f$). This is a way of describing the idea that $A$ can be computed from $B$, though, as @William indicated, this is not the most general way since a single pre-specified question about $B$ is too stringent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a standard r.e. set is $A=\{x:W_x\ne \emptyset\}$. For each $x$, we can define a function 
$$g_x(n)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } (\exists m)[\varphi_x(m)\downarrow]\\
\uparrow &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and let $f$ be the function which takes $x$ to an index of $g_x$ (i.e. some $y$ such that $g_x=\varphi_y$).

Comment: Thank you! It's so simple as soon as you understand how it works. On question though: Why is $f$ recursive? I'm guessing that I'm missing some simple fact about it.

Comment: @Hashmush Well $f(x)$ is just the Godel number (or whatever enumeration you choose) of $g_x$, and the definition I've given can be turned into a Godel number by some standard algorithm (the algorithm being independent of $x$), after you replace $\varphi_x$ with the symbols defining $\varphi_x$.

Comment: @Hashmush He's employing the [Church-Turing thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) to conclude $f$ is computable (because proving it rigorously would very tedious).

Answer (score 1):

Let $H = \{(e,x) : \Phi_e(x)\downarrow\} = \{(e,x) : x \in W_e\}$. $H$ is your standard Halting Problem set, which asserts that $(e,x) \in H$ if and only if the $e^\text{th}$ Turing program halts on input $x$.

A very useful fact is that $H \equiv_m K$, i.e. $H \leq_m K$ and $K \leq_m H$. It is clear that $K \leq_m H$. To show $H \leq_m K$, there exists a computable function $f$ such that $\Phi_{f(e,x)}(z)$ halts on any input $z$ if and only if $\Phi_e(x) \downarrow$. To precisely prove that $f$ is computable, you will likely need to use the s-m-n theorem. However appealing the Churing-Turing Thesis, given $e$, $x$, and $z$, make a program $\Psi$ such that $\Psi(e,x,z)$ halts if and only if $\Phi_e(x)\downarrow$ (note $z$ is not used at all). Because of the obvious uniformity (or use s-m-n theorem to be precise), there is a computable $f$ such that $\Psi(e,x,z) = \Phi_{f(e,x)}(z)$. Then $x \in H$ if and only if $\Phi_{f(e,x)}(f(e,x)) \downarrow$ if and only if $f(e,x) \in K$.

Hence this shows that $H \equiv_m K$.

Now to prove that $A$ is c.e. if and only if $A \leq_m K$. If $A$ is c.e., by definition $A = W_e = \text{dom}(\Phi_e)$ for some $e$. Hence $x \in W_e$ if and only if $(e,x) \in H$. Thus $A \leq_m H$ using the computable function $f(x) = (e,x)$. Since it was just shown that $H \leq_m K$, $A \leq_m K$ by transitivity of $\leq_m$. Suppose $A \leq_m K$. Then there is a computable function $f$ such that $x \in A$ if and only if $f(x) \in K$. Since $K$ is c.e., define

$\Psi(x) \begin{cases}
1 & \quad f(n) \in K \\
\uparrow & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

is a partial computable function. hence $\Psi = \Phi_i$ for some $i$. Then $x \in A$ if and only if $\Psi(x) \downarrow$ if and only $x \in \text{dom}(\Phi_i)$ if and only if $x \in W_i$. Hence $A = W_i$. Thus $A$ is c.e.

---

This result shows that $K$ is $m$-complete, which is means every c.e. set is reducible to it. Another example, which is also a standard exercise in $m$-reducibility, is to show that $\{e : W_e \neq \emptyset\}$ is also $m$-equivalent to $K$.

An obvious example is $\emptyset \leq_m K$, but $K \not\leq_m \emptyset$.

---

$A \leq_m B$ means roughtly that there is a "very computable procedure" to determine membership in $A$ if you know about membership in $B$. So to solve reduciblity questions, you should think about how use $B$ to know about $A$, as in the example of obtaining above, where I reduced $H$ to $K$ and $K$ to $H$.

I say "very computable procedure" because there is a more general notion of Turing reducibility $A \leq_T B$, which more accurately means knowing $A$ computably from $B$.

Comment: Thank you, though I explicitly stated that I didn't want you to solve it. Just provide examples.